# Johansen cointegration test: interpret the result

Tags: multivariate-analysis, cointegration, unit-root, stationarity

I am trying to develop a stationary time series with 6 variables in Matlab. Can anyone tell me whether the 6 variables are cointegrated? The results I got are:

[image]

Comment: *you are telling me that the six variables are not cointegrated and only the first two ones are cointegrated?* No. The cointegration takes place in the given system of variables (in this case, six variables). The question is, what is the cointegration rank, or alternatively, how many underlying random walks there are in the system. The table tells you that. I recommend Davidson & McKinnon ["Econometric Theory and Methods"](http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/ETM/) for an easy introduction into the subject.

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 8):

When examining the table you should go down row by row comparing the test statistic to the critical value, and see when you cannot reject the null hypothesis for the first time, for a chosen significance level. That will show whether the series are cointegrated and what the cointegration rank is.

- If you cannot reject `rank<=0`, the series are integrated but not cointegrated.
- If you reject all the cases including the maximum rank (here `rank<=6`), the series are not integrated to begin with (and hence there is no cointegration).
- If you reject `rank<=0` but stop before or at the maximum rank, the series are integrated and cointegrated, and the cointegration rank is the one at which you stopped (could not reject).

For example, choose 5% significance level. Then the first non-rejection when using the trace statistic is at `r<=3`, and the same is true for the eigenvalue statistic. Hence, you do not reject the null hypothesis that the data is cointegrated and the cointegration rank is 3.

Comment: This shows you how to interpret the table. However, it is not clear what you are up to in general and whether this table is relevant to what you are trying to achieve. It would help if you edited the post to include more specific information.

Comment: +1 For example, there are different tables for different specifications of the deterministic part of the model, and it is possible that the one you chose is not appropriate to your problem.

Comment: And what happens when you have mixed results? i.e. you cannot reject `rank<=0` but you can reject `rank<=1`? Do you take only the first result?

Comment: @tsando, you start from `rank<=0`. If you cannot reject, you conclude the series are integrated but not cointegrated. You do not proceed down the table if you cannot reject a row. Thus you do not consider the row `rank<=1` at all. It is just how the procedure is supposed to work.

Comment: ok. If I have only a two time series and I can reject all the cases including the maximum rank with 5% (there is no cointegration) rank <= 2, but I stop in the middle with 1% confidence (rank <= 1)? What should I do?

Comment: @ooolllooo, consider posting this as a separate question.